# force data-link to open a new window

Tags: jquery

Can someone please tell me how to force this code to open a new window?
It keeps loading in the same window.

```
$("[data-link]").click(function() {
    window.open = $(this).attr("data-link");
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

window.open is a function that you need to pass the address to. While you are changing the code instead of using the attr function of jQuery use the data function.

```
$("[data-link]").click(function() {
    window.open($(this).data("link"),'_blank');
    return false;
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/rap04tma/

window.open(URL,name,specs,replace)

**name:**

- _blank - URL is loaded into a new window. This is default
- _parent - URL is loaded into the parent frame
- _self - URL replaces the current page
- _top - URL replaces any framesets that may be loaded
- name - The name of the window (Note: the name does not specify the title of the new window)